# Pourquoi conjugue-t-on différemment `on part dès que tu es prêt` et `j'attends que tu sois prêt` alors que les 2 propositions expriment la certitude ?

Tags: conjugaison, subjonctif

Le subjonctif est censé être utilisé lorsque l'idée décrite n'est pas considérée comme certaine, or

> j'attends que tu sois prêt

exprime clairement selon moi que le narrateur est certain de l'issue de la situation, i.e. que la personne sera définitivement prête au bout d'un moment. En tout cas bien plus certain que pour la phrase

> Je pense que tu es capable de réussir

qui elle conjugue le verbe à l'indicatif...

Au vu des deux autres phrases que j'ai citées, je n'arrive pas à trouver d'explication logique sur pourquoi l'on ne dit pas

> j'attends que tu es prêt.

Comment: C'est loin d'être la seule exception au "principe" de la virtualité/incertitude... il y a des théories là-dessus https://www.cairn.info/revue-syntaxe-et-semantique-2016-1-page-57.htm,

Comment: L'idée qui circule selon laquelle le subjonctif exprimerait une incertitude est fausse. Il y a une corrélation, qui plus est, relativement ténue, mais c'est tout. C'est plus une opposition entre thèse (ce que l'on soutient) et hypothèse (ce dont on parle, souvent considéré acquis plutôt qu'incertain, qui apparait souvent dans des subordonnées conjonctives)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. ***Dès que tu es prêt*** indique une condition préalable, on postule qu'elle est vérifiée pour pouvoir utiliser l'indicatif dans la principale. Si c'était une hypothèse, le conditionnel serait utilisé :

   > *On **partirait** dès que tu **serais** prêt.*
2. On n'entend pas vraiment ***J'attends que tu es prêt*** car, d'une part, il n'est pas prêt au moment où on s'exprime et d'autre part, on n'affirme pas que l'événement va arriver.

   S'agissant d'un événement futur, on peut parfois entendre en français relâché :

   > ***J'attends quand tu seras prêt.***

   L'usage est sinon d'utiliser le subjonctif après ***attendre***, l'idée étant qu'on ne peut pas être sûr de la survenue de quelque chose qu'on attend. On trouve d'ailleurs bien le présent quand la certitude est explicite :

   > *Je **sais** qu'il **est**/**sera** prêt.*
   > *J'**annonce** qu'il **est**/**sera** prêt.*
   > *Je **confirme** qu'il **est**/**sera** prêt.*

   On trouve cependant dans le [dictionnaire de l'Académie](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/attendre) :

   > *Je m'**attends** que vous **viendrez** nous voir.*

   Cette tournure indiquée comme littéraire choque les oreilles contemporaines (ou au moins les miennes...)

   Le choix du mode existe avec certains verbes :

   > *Je **comprends** qu'il **vient** demain.*  (d'après ce que je comprends, il viendra demain)
   > *Je **comprends** qu'il **vienne** demain.*  (je comprends son choix de venir demain)
   > *Je **comprends** qu'il **viendrait** demain.* (d'après ce que je comprends, il viendra peut-être demain)

Comment: « Je comprends qu'il viendrait demain. » Mes esgourdes ont tout un coup des acouphènes. Laissons cela aux sonotones-sous-la-coupole. Débuchons le conditionnel inaudible du verbe pour l'affirmer en deux syllabes : « Je comprends qu'il viendra peut-être demain. »

Comment: @Personne Mes oreilles me trompent peut-être mais restent de marbre. « J'ai ouï dire qu'il viendrait demain, c'est du moins ce que je comprends. »

Comment: Bien sûr, cela fonctionne, surtout à l'écrit, avec un temps passé et un verbe qui enregistre une information incertaine reçue de l'extérieur… « J'ai compris [sous-entendu, après étude d'une situation] qu'il viendrait demain… *ou pas* ». La musique des mots compte bien plus que les arrangements grammaticaux. Par habitude, certes coupable : « demain je viendr***é*** » = ‘futur’ vs ‘conditionnel’ = *ké ki dit* ?, « demain il viendr***é*** » =  *koment ki kause* ? : si ‘demain’, alors il y a ‘viendr***a***’. Le conditionnel est bien inaudible, s'il n'est pas ‘encadré’… ton exemple va dans ce sens.

Comment: @Personne en rapport avec le conditionnel inaudible, cela dépend surtout de la prononciation. Venant d'une région où le conditionnel et le futur ont une prononciation différente ("demain je viendr**é**" vs "demain il viendr**è**"), "Je comprends qu'il viendrait demain" n'a aucune ambiguïté ni fausse sonorité pour ma part

Comment: @AloisChristen *On a bien compris que je viendra pas demain.* ;-)

Comment: @AloisChristen … certes, il y a des régions qui y sont sensibles, mais, de nos jours, de nombreux bacheliers sont obligés de prendre des cours d'orthographe, alors que pour ceux qui se déscolarisent plus tôt, l'adjectif conditionnel se conjugue souvent après “liberté …”